# How can i make my bot send a webhook after someone use a command?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

So, I have a "Whitelist" command and I want my bot to send a webhook that says "New whitelist request" for example, and I can't figure out how to.

Here's the code:

```py
@client.tree.command(guild=TEST_GUILD, description="Whitelist")
async def whitelist(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    # Send the modal with an instance of our `Whitelist` class
    # Since modals require an interaction, they cannot be done as a response to a text command.
    # They can only be done as a response to either an application command or a button press.
    await interaction.response.send_modal(Whitelist())
```

Tried to follow the documentation by adding :

```py
webhook = DiscordWebhook(url="your webhook url", content="Webhook Message")
response = webhook.execute()
```

And I tried adding webhook URL to my response but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got that from, but it certainly isn't the right [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

From the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Webhook),

```
from discord import Webhook
import aiohttp

async def foo():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        webhook = Webhook.from_url('url-here', session=session)
        await webhook.send(content='Hello World', username='Foo')
```

`DiscordWebhook` doesn't exist, unless you're importing from a third-party module.

Read more on [discord.Webhook](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [Webhook.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Webhook.send).

Comment: Thanks ! Now , how can i add it to my command ? (Like in the question)